# Insert img from folder into sqlite to show in Android app

Tags: android, sqlite, blob

am I new in Android develop and I have app with sqlite database. **My question is, how to insert a lot of images in my folder into sqlite database and after that, save this database into SDCard, then show images in my app.** Is there any way how to save it ?

My database like:

```
String CREATE_TABLE_TEST="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + KEY_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_NAZEV +" TEXT,"
            + KEY_OBJEM +" TEXT,"
            + KEY_OBSAH +" TEXT,"
            + KEY_AROMA +" TEXT,"
            + KEY_CHUT +" TEXT,"
            + KEY_DOKONCENI +" TEXT,"
            + KEY_POZNAMKA +" TEXT,"
            + KEY_POTO  +" BLOB" + ")";
```

I have problem with BLOB, is there any examples, please, if you want to me help, please add code it will be work. I am lost, how to insert images from C:\AndroidApp\Images.....1 000 images.

Thank you very much

Comment: You can't insert images from your C drive. Your app doesn't have access to your local windows computer

Comment: Why can't you copy the images directly to the SD card? Why do you need a BLOB which you'll just convert back to an image?

Comment: Because, I have images in my PC, but i need to show them in my Android app. If I want to insert images in my Android app, I can insert only one. BUT I need insert more about 1000 images. I didnt want to insert one by one. Is there any help ??

Comment: What do you mean you can insert only one? Also, I think you should really use a web server to host the images rather than force them all into an app since there is a size limit to an APK

Comment: And what about offline database with images ? I need the store Image and retrive them.

Comment: If you make an `assets` directory in Android Studio, that gets copied to a read only location in your app, but like I said, your app size will be limited, so 1000 images, doesn't seem likely. However, that's one of the only ways that you can copy you images into your app at runtime. If you need them in a database, you can do that in your SqliteOpenHelper